# Linear functionals on $n \times n $matrices over $ \mathbb{F}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need to show that all linear transformations on the above vector space is of the form $f_B(A)=trace(B^TA)$ for some $n \times n$ matrix $B$.How to proceed?I have just been able to show that $f_B$ is a linear functional .Any form of hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can indentify $M(n,\Bbb F)$ with $\Bbb F^{n^2}$. Now all the linear functionals $f$ on $\Bbb F^{n^2}$ are of the form $f(x) = v^Tx$ for some fixed $v$ which depends on $f$. Use this to $v$ to construct the matrix $B$. I'll illustrate this for the case $n=2$:

Let $v = (v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$. So the matrix $B$ will be

\begin{equation}
B = \begin{bmatrix}v_1 &v_2\\ v_3 & v_4\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Now if $X \in M(2,\Bbb F)$, then

\begin{equation}
trace(B^TX) = trace\left(\begin{bmatrix}v_1 &v_3\\ v_2 & v_4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1 &x_2\\ x_3 & x_4\end{bmatrix} \right) = v_1x_1+v_2x_2+v_3x_3+v_4x_4
\end{equation}

and this is precisely what you'll obtain with the identification $M(2,\Bbb F) \cong \Bbb F^{n^2}$.